# How do I store one session variable for some time even after closing the browser in Flask?

Tags: authentication, flask, session, session-cookies, flask-login

I am using Flask-Login's function login() with remember=True.

This is working fine. But recently I implemented a Two-factor authentication where the user has to download an authenticator app to be able to login.

I created my own `@tfa_required` decorator that uses `@login_required` in case the user enabled TFA. The way I keep track of the login status is with a session variable called `auth_level` to know whether the user successfully logged in using TFA. (code snippets attached).

Assume that the user logged in to a browser which then closed it. He would still be logged in (Since he is logged in with remember = True), but he will have to enter TFA again (`auth_level=1` -- meaning TFA is not successful yet -- now instead of `auth_level=2`).

What I really want is to store `auth_level` session variable for as long as Flask-Login remembers that the user logged in, even after closing the browser.

As far as I understand, Flask-Login uses a different session to store the login-related variables so that the user is still logged in for some time.

How do I make the client remember `auth_level` even after closing the browser?

Thank you.

```
# Decorator for TFA-required views
def tfa_login_required(f):
    """Implement additional TFA checking, on top of login_required.

    TFA is only checked if it has been activated for the user.
    """
    @wraps(f)
    @login_required
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        # if the user is authenticated and has tfa enabled but not tfa passed
        if (
            current_user.tfa_enabled
            and session.get('auth_level') != 2
        ):
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login_view'))
        # if authenticated proceed normally
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Example of using login_required **without** tfa_required:

```
@auth.route('/logout/')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session['auth_level'] = 0
    session.modified = True
    return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```

Example using both, tfa_required AND login_required:

```
@main.route('/some_route/', methods=['GET'])
@tfa_login_required
def some_route():
    do_some_work_that_requires_full_authentication()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Flask-Login cookies themselves to include the variable in the Flask-Login cookie. For reference, here is the code:

```
from flask_login import (
....
COOKIE_DURATION,
COOKIE_SECURE,
COOKIE_HTTPONLY,
encode_cookie,
)
```

In the view function, instead of returning `url_for(...)`, I create a response object with `make_response()` and set the response cookie using the following:

```
    response = make_response(redirect(url_for('...')))

    # Setting cookie similar to Flask Login way of setting its cookies
    duration = current_app.config.get('REMEMBER_COOKIE_DURATION', COOKIE_DURATION)
    secure = current_app.config.get('REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE', COOKIE_SECURE)
    httponly = current_app.config.get('REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY', COOKIE_HTTPONLY)
    expires = duration + datetime.utcnow()

    # encode additional data to ensure that the user cannot simply use the value
    # from the remember cookie
    data = encode_cookie(str(session['_user_id']) + '_cookie_variable')

    response.set_cookie(
        'cookie_variable',
        value=data,
        expires=expires,
        secure=secure,
        httponly=httponly
    )
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`this`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=session#flask.session.permanent)

By default, Flask deletes all session data if the tab is closed. In order to make it permanent, do something like this:

```py
@app.before_request
    def set_permanent_session():
        session.permanent = True
```